# Is it more secure to prefix a password hash with a salt or to dissolve the salt within the hash?

Tags: php, security, hash, passwords

Say I have two strings, a hash and a salt

```
$hash = "1234567890";
$salt = "abcdefghij";
```

Is it more secure to prefix the hash with the salt

```
$password = "abcdefghij1234567890";
```

Or to dissolve the salt within the hash

```
$password = "a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0";
```

The second one seems more secure, but is it?

**Edit:** I am currently using the SHA512 method to create a 128-bit hash and 128-bit salt.

Comment: What is the purpose of a salt?  Is that affected by the above choice?

Comment: It's not the "password" that matters, it's the "hash" and the "salt". Choosing a complex hash and salt, will lessen the chances of being "figured out", if I can say. Using `crypt`, `bcrypt` or better yet, PHP's [`password hash`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) function is a good start.

Comment: @user3236661 SHA-512 creates 512 bit hashes, hence the name.

Comment: my bad, @gumbo i meant 128 byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not matter assuming you are using a decent hashing algorithm.
Talking of that, you should really use bcrypt for password hashing, which takes the salt as a separate parameter anyways.

However, you should not add your salt to the hash but to the password *before* hashing. Otherways it's pretty useless.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you should prefix the **plaintext password** with the salt and *then* hash the whole thing. That way, it becomes practically impossible to retrieve a hash of the password to brute-force or search for in a look-up table. If you just prefix the hash with a salt, the salt will be easily recognizable once an attacker sees 2 or more salted hashes next to the other.

Comment: I'm assuming the OP is talking about how to store the combination of the hash and the salt.